# Optimizing queries graphs Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am working on a dashboard to show graphs from measurements. I have difficulties to get this data processed efficiently/quickly with Rails (6).

Its 5 graphs(temperature, moisture..) all showing data from the **same** timespan, in **every** graph is an avarage, a minimum and a maximum. So its 15 datasets total on the page.

Every measurement(record) has five columns(temperature, moisture..) with the different readings of the measurement. The amount of measurements for the graph can vary between +- 3000 records to 100.000+. These measurements are grouped by month. Minimum, maximum and average dataset are then calculated. So all these 15 datasets are based on the **same** records.

My idea was to load the measurement from database once and perform calculations on it. So I dont have to query the data for every dataset. I use the Groupdate gem(https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) to quickly group the measurements by month when querying them from database. then I can monthly average, minimum and maximum.

Unfortunately I get a query for every calculation. Which makes the page load slow.. Any idea how I can optimize loading measurements from the database? I can focus on refractoring the code after.

```
def dashboard_device
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    @last_measurement = @device.measurements.last
    @weather_forecast_location = @device.sublocation.location
    start_date = Date.parse('1-1-2020')
    end_date = Date.parse('31-12-2020')

    selected_measurements = @device.measurements.select(:measurement_date, :moisture, :temperature, :dielectricity, :conductivity, :salinity).group_by_month(:measurement_date, range: start_date..end_date, format: '%B')

    @moisture = selected_measurements.average(:moisture).compact
    @moisture_max = selected_measurements.maximum(:moisture).compact
    @moisture_min = selected_measurements.minimum(:moisture).compact

    @temperature = selected_measurements.average(:temperature).compact
    @temperature_max = selected_measurements.maximum(:temperature).compact
    @temperature_min = selected_measurements.minimum(:temperature).compact

    @dielectricity = selected_measurements.average(:dielectricity).compact
    @dielectricity_max = selected_measurements.maximum(:dielectricity).compact
    @dielectricity_min = selected_measurements.minimum(:dielectricity).compact

    @conductivity = selected_measurements.average(:conductivity).compact
    @conductivity_max = selected_measurements.maximum(:conductivity).compact
    @conductivity_min = selected_measurements.minimum(:conductivity).compact

    @salinity = selected_measurements.average(:salinity).compact
    @salinity_max = selected_measurements.maximum(:salinity).compact
    @salinity_min = selected_measurements.minimum(:salinity).compact

    render 'dashboard'
  end
```

**Update**

Using pluck seems to work, but unfortunately I dont get months which the data corresponds to.

changing controller to

```
selected_measurements = @device.measurements.select(:measurement_date, :moisture, :temperature, :dielectricity, :conductivity, :salinity).group_by_month(:measurement_date, range: start_date..end_date, format: '%B')

    result = selected_measurements.select('MAX(moisture)', 'AVG(moisture)', 'MIN(moisture)')
```

Seems to be nearly there, however it gives an error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "measurements.measurement_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: You should be selecting aggregates in the database instead of doing the number crunching in Ruby. You can select aggregates with strings `.select('AVG(moisture) AS avg_moisure')`. Or by using Arel `Measurement.arel_table[:moisture].average.as('avg_moisure')`.

Comment: If you are regulary querying the same aggregates create  a SQL view or a table that contains monthly aggregates which are generated by running a cron tab.

Comment: Is this `group_by_month` coming from some gem?

Comment: Yes, it is the Groupdate gem (https://github.com/ankane/groupdate)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom select statement

```
@moisture = selected_measurements.average(:moisture).compact
@moisture_max = selected_measurements.maximum(:moisture).compact
@moisture_min = selected_measurements.minimum(:moisture).compact
```

Like this somehow...

```
result = selected_measurements.select("MAX(moisture) as max_moisture, AVG(moisture), MIN(moisture)")
result.first.max_moisture
```

or with a pluck if you just need the values

```
result = selected_measurements.pluck("MAX(moisture), AVG(moisture), MIN(moisture)")
```